# Аутентификация в Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Пытаюсь реализовать аунтификацию по [образцу](http://railstutorial.ru/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-a_working_sign_in_method)

И наткнулся на проблему в лице функции "signed_in?"

```
def signed_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end
```

С объектом current_user работаем след. образом

```
def current_user=(user)
  @current_user = user
end

def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end

def sign_in(user)
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  self.current_user = user
end

def signed_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end

def sign_out
  self.current_user = nil
  cookies.delete(:remember_token)
end
```

И проблема в том, что функция каждый раз присылает мне значение true, даже если зайти и выйти из учетки, с помощью sign_out.

Ошибка была, из-за того, что у меня в базе были старые пользователи с  remember_token = NULL.
Вопрос можно закрывать :)

Comment: Похоже что `@current_user` не зануляется.

Пробуйте отладить метод `sign_out`.

Comment: Определите для себя - вы сейчас хотите ВСЁ изучить, или вам ехать надо?

В каждом проекте, который вы будете делать на рельсах, будет Devise. Изучите лучше его.

Comment: ау*тен*тификация